# Rails3.2からRails4.0に上げたらroutingでArgumentErrorが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

システムをRails3.2最新からRails4.0最新にアップグレードしました。そこでRailsを起動するとroutesの設定でエラーが出るようになりました。↓エラー内容

```
[hoge@korekore 4.0_app]$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:430:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'apl_nw_login'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1484:in `add_route'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1461:in `decomposed_match'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1442:in `block in match'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1433:in `each'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1433:in `match'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:626:in `map_method'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:595:in `post'
        from /hogehoge/workspace/4.0_app/config/routes.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:877:in `block in constraints'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:753:in `scope'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:877:in `constraints'
        from /hogehoge/workspace/4.0_app/config/routes.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:753:in `scope'
        from /hogehoge/workspace/4.0_app/config/routes.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:818:in `block in namespace'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:753:in `scope'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:818:in `namespace'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `namespace'
        from /hogehoge/workspace/4.0_app/config/routes.rb:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
        from /hogehoge/workspace/4.0_app/config/routes.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /hogehoge/workspace/4.0_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from /hogehoge/workspace/4.0_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /hogehoge/workspace/4.0_app/config.ru:in `new'
        from /hogehoge/workspace/4.0_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        from /hogehoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/4.0rails/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

実装config/routes.rbでscopeを分けてログイン画面を分けています。
エラーの原因はas => :nw_loginが被ってるせいだとは分かっているのですが、できればnw_login等の名前を変えずに対応したいと思っています。何か対応方法はありますでしょうか？

```
 namespace :apl, :path => "/a" do
   scope :module => :adm do
     get "login" => "login#index", :as => :nw_login
     post "login" => "login#login", :as => :login
   end
 end

 namespace :apl, :path => "/a" do
   scope ":name", :module => :manage do
     get "login" => "login#index", :as => :nw_login
     post "login" => "login#login", :as => :login
```

Rubyバージョンは2.2.3
Pathは↓の感じで出ることを期待してます。Rails3.2では出てました。

```
2015/10/30 14:17:34 [INFO] :: Connecting to database specified by database.yml
                                  apl_nw_login GET    /a/login(.:format)                                                                                  apl/adm/login#index
                                  apl_nw_login GET    /a/:name/login(.:format)                                                                     apl/manage/login#index
                                     apl_login POST   /a/login(.:format)                                                                                  apl/adm/login#login
                                      apl_login POST   /a/:name/login(.:format)                                                                     apl/manage/login#login
```

Comment: nw_login_pathの期待している出力結果は何ですか？（3.2では何が出力されていたのですか？）

Comment: 期待しているpathを追加しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「エラーの原因はas => :nw_loginが被ってるせいだとは分かっているのですが、できればnw_login等の名前を変えずに対応したい」とのことですが、Rails 4で仕様が変わったのでそれは無理だと思います。

Railsのメジャーバージョンアップでは多かれ少なかれ既存のコードを修正する必要が出てくるので、諦めて新しいパス名を付けて、既存のコードを修正してください。

参考までに修正例を載せておきます。

```
# routes.rb
namespace :apl, :path => "/a" do
   scope :module => :adm do
     get "login" => "login#index", :as => :nw_login
     post "login" => "login#login", :as => :login
   end
 end

 namespace :apl, :path => "/a" do
   scope ":name", :module => :manage do
     get "login" => "login#index", :as => :name_nw_login
     post "login" => "login#login", :as => :name_login

 # view
 <%= link_to 'ログイン', apl_name_nw_login_path %>
```

Comment: やはりnw_loginを変更するしかないのですね。修正例ありがとうございます。